# Is there any relation between Curried function/ Partially applied function and Higher order functions in scala

Tags: scala

I have a confusion between higher-order function and partially applied function. Can I say the partially applied function is Higher-order function because partially applied function also return function?

Answer (score 1):

Higher order function is the fact that you can pass one or multiple functions as parameters or have them as a result. Functions are the same as variables. whereas currying is when a function has  multiple parameters and you precise only a few of them so you obtain a new function. So currying can be seen as an example of higher order function because you return a function when you use currying.
Currying example:

```
def plus(a :Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b
def plus5 = plus(5)
```

plus5 is a function and that's a kind of higher order function.

Comment: "Higher order function is the fact that you can pass one or multiple functions as parameters or have them as a result" Higher order function is that's it's possible to pass a function B as argument of function A.

Comment: And what about partially applied function? Is it also a higher-order function?

Comment: a partial function is a function of `T` not able to handle all the possible `T` values (not defined for the whole domain/category)

Comment: @cchantep sorry I am talking about partially applied function.

Comment: partially applied function is related to [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying); `def foo(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b; val bar: Int => Int = foo(5, _: Int)`

Comment: Partially applied function is the same as currying

Comment: You mean both currying and partially applied function are not higher-order functions right?

Comment: No Sorry, I meant they are kind of Higer order function because they output a method. I'll try to make my answer clearer

Answer (score 1):

Partially applied function is the *result* of the process of partial application. This resulting function does not necessarily have to be higher-order, for example consider

```
val f: (Int, Int) => (Int) = (a, b) => a + b
val g: Int => Int = f(1, _) //  g is partially applied function
```

Here function `g` is a partially applied function and yet it is first-order `Int => Int`. However the process of partial application itself is indeed a higher-order process as it takes a function and returns a function, similar to, perhaps, differential operator from calculus which also takes a function as input and returns a function as output.

As a side-note, currying and partial application are related but [not identical](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/partially-applied-functions-currying-in-scala#currying-vs-partially-applied-functions).

Comment: Are Partially applied function and currying also Higher-order function?